# Laravel 5 - Cannot get authenticated user from subdomain despite setting universal session domain

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have 2 Laravel projects (one is 5.4, the other is 5.7) installed on the same server, currently dev'ing via Valet in my local environment.

What I'm doing now is trying to direct users from `example.app` to `booking.example.app` as the Booking site requires an app for itself.

However, after logging in `example.app`, opening `booking.example.app` would show me I'm not authenticated (i.e. `dd(Auth::check())` returns null). I have done sub-domain cookie/session sharing before and never came across this before.

Both app has the following configurations:

**example.app**

> SESSION_DOMAIN=.example.app
>
> SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
>
> SESSION_COOKIE=example_session

**booking.example.app**

> SESSION_DOMAIN=booking.example.app
>
> SESSION_DRIVER=cookie
>
> SESSION_COOKIE=example_session

What am I missing here?

Comment: You should upgrade your 5.4 laravel. Laravel 5.7 does not store the session in cookies in the same way that 5,4 does

Comment: I made both 5.4 but the same thing's still happening... Tried switching to `cookie` or `database` session storage too. Do you know what could be the cause?